# Gradle error while setting up LibGDX with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to setup a libGdx with eclipse using this [tutorial](http://www.toxsickproductions.com/libgdx/how-to-setup-your-libgdx-project/) 
but when I try to build the project I got this error

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'TestGame'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.5.
     Required by:
         :TestGame:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin
/0.5/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.5.pom'.
         > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/de/richsource/gradle/plugins/gwt-gradle-plugin/0.
5/gwt-gradle-plugin-0.5.pom'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13+.
     Required by:
         :TestGame:unspecified
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/buil
d/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-met
adata.xml'.
               > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
      > Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/g
radle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metada
ta.xml'.
               > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused
   > Could not resolve org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha-04.
     Required by:
         :TestGame:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha-04
/robovm-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha-04.pom'.
         > Connection to https://repo1.maven.org refused
      > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/robovm/robovm-gradle-plugin/1.0.0-alpha-04/ro
bovm-gradle-plugin-1.0.0-alpha-04.pom'.
         > Connection to https://jcenter.bintray.com refused

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more l
og output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 12.602 secs
```

And the libGDX ui generated this build gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'de.richsource.gradle.plugins:gwt-gradle-plugin:0.5'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13+'
        classpath 'org.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-alpha-04'
    }
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"
    apply plugin: "idea"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = 'TestingGame'
        gdxVersion = '1.4.1'
        roboVMVersion = '1.0.0-alpha-04'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:1.2"
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "robovm"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-rt:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "org.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:${roboVMVersion}"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"


    dependencies {
        compile project(":core")
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:1.2:sources"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.box2dlights:box2dlights:1.2"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

I Know Maven but I don't know gradle so I can't understand the exception and where I've gone wrong even I did everything in the tutorial, any help please?

Comment: Random idea, but try using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12+` instead of `0.13+`. Also, make sure no firewall is preventing Gradle from communicating with the repositories (another random idea).

Comment: @Zhuinden thanks for response i just try it but same error

Comment: Do You have any firewall, proxy server etc?

Comment: @Opal yes i have an NTLM and i have set the gradle.proporties file as mentioned in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

Comment: Apparently that's not working correctly. Double-check the proxy properties and check the `--debug` log for proxy related messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching i found that i need to add the GWT that i downloaded to the eclipse plugin and that was not mentioned in the tutorial

so what i did is

```
in eclipse go to  WINDOWS --->PREFERENCE--->GOOGLE ---->WEB TOOLKIT --->add and search for the folder you have extracted its ZIP file
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with Gradle (*Could not GET 'https...*) but with a different project. I'm behind a firewall as well

I tried using a separate gradle.properties and also tried passing the proxy server/port to gradle via the VM arguments as mentioned by some other posts on SO but neither of those worked

Here's a way I found via Eclipse settings that worked for me

Under ***Window->Preferences->Network Connections*** set the Active Provider to Manual

[image: settings]

.

Then edit the entries for HTTP and HTTPS and add the proxy server and port there. If your proxy needs your credentials make sure you add those there as well. Try building it again and hopefully it works this time